# google app engine - python, iterate through data model properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the following code, I wish to iterate through all the variables of userData Object. I would like to know how to do it. The code, **myString += eachObject.everyElement**, is where I find the problem. I am not able to figure out how to iterate through every element of an object.

```
class userData(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    nationality = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

class MyApp(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        listOfUserData = ['name', 'age', 'nationality', 'date']
        myString= ""
        #Here, I have few userData objects and I wish to get all
        #the userData perperties and form a string
        myUserDataObjects = [userData1, userData2, userData3]
        for eachObject in myUserDataObjects:
            for everyElement in listOfUserData:
                ######################################
                #This is the place where I need help##
                ######################################
                myString += eachObject.everyElement
        self.response.out.write(myString)
```

I know that I can access the elements by writing as 
    eachObject.name + eachObject.age + ..., But I am against doing it, because if I do it and I plan to add a new property to the userData, I would have to change the code inside the for loop too. Rather I just plan to add that property to the listOfUserData which makes it easier.

Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Krishna Chaitanya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#getattr) method to get an attribute from an object. In your code sample, the following should work:

```
myString += getattr(eachObject, everyElement)
```